# Why did I lose a point on a question that I had nothing to do with?

Tags: support, reputation

Exactly one point was deducted from my total for no reason. The link takes me to someone else’s question, where I posted neither an answer nor a comment. All I ever did was read the page. What is going on?

The question is here: [Does every logically possible event have a non zero probability?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97136/does-every-logically-possible-event-have-a-non-zero-probability/97142#97142)

Mark Andrews

Comment: Could it be that you accidentally hit a downvote triangle? 1 point deduction is probably a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked your rep history and it shows no -1 rep drops for at least 3 months.

It might be the system repaired some glitch that was not protocolled. That said, -1 rep deductions use to be *downvotes cast by yourself* (casting a downvote gives -1, receiving one gives -2).

Thus, whenever that happens, you might want to look at forgotten deliberate or even unintentional downvote casts in the question thread.

Comment: Thank you. And I am adding this sentence in order to reach 5 additional characters.